# Mock fails to block expensive resources

Tags: python, mocking, python-dataclasses

In the following minimal code samples I show what should be two identical classes. Both versions work correctly in the original source from which this extract has been drawn.

The problem is a normally valid tkinter error message that appears to be wrongly generated. Please note there are many SO questions about this all of which relate to the **correct** production of the error message.

One of the classes `Factory` always fails on test. The other `PostInit` has two tests; one works and the other fails. The  tests were written for the pytest framework.

The failure is the tkinter error:

> RuntimeError: Too early to create variable: no default root window

The passing test `test_post_init` mocks and blocks the whole of `tkinter`.  When the mock is commented out in `test_tk_unmocked` the tkinter error is produced. I assume this demonstrates the correct production of the error message.

In the always failing `test_factory` tkinter is again completely mocked but still manages to produce an error message from deep inside Tk/Tcl.

How is `test_factory` managing to bypass the mocking of `tkinter` in the line `monkeypatch.setattr(patterns_so, "tk", MagicMock())`?

```
"""patterns_so.py"""

from dataclasses import dataclass, field
import tkinter as tk


@dataclass
class PostInit:
    # Passes if tkinter is mocked.
    textvariable: tk.StringVar = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.textvariable = tk.StringVar()


@dataclass
class Factory:
    # Always fails.
    _textvariable: tk.StringVar = field(
        default_factory=tk.StringVar, init=False, repr=False
    )
```

```
"""test_patterns_so.py"""

from unittest.mock import MagicMock

import patterns_so


class TestFacade:
    def test_post_init(self, monkeypatch):
        # Passes.
        monkeypatch.setattr(patterns_so, "tk", MagicMock())
        patterns_so.PostInit()

    def test_tk_unmocked(self, monkeypatch):
        # Expected fail.
        # monkeypatch.setattr(patterns_so, "tk", MagicMock())
        patterns_so.PostInit()

    def test_factory(self, monkeypatch):
        # Unexpected fail.
        monkeypatch.setattr(patterns_so, "tk", MagicMock())
        patterns_so.Factory()
```

#### Postscript

The fundamental problem appears to be premature instantiation by the mechanics of the dataclasses module.

Very near the bottom of the docs† on `dataclasses` there is a note which says `init=False` will be ignored when a default_factory is present and so it **will** be included in the generated `__init__`. I confirmed this with further testing.

Naïve me thought that `__init__` only got run when the class was instantiated.
According to the docs `__init__` calls `__post_init__`. I beg to differ. The observed behavior here suggests that the generated `__init__` function is actually run when the class is created ***not later*** when it is instantiated. After instantiation the `__post_init__` function will run.

In cases where the mock is intended to prevent an expensive or persistent resource from being started it will fail: The resource will be started.

Any method which forcibly delays instantiation of mocked attributes will work. Either Riccardo Bucco's lambda or my example using `__post_init__` ensure success.

Thanks to [Riccardo Bucco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5296106/riccardo-bucco) for guiding me to this deeper understanding of dataclasses.

†bottom of the docs: aka ‘The small print’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ensure `tk.StringVar` is not called upon class definition but is instead called within a method or function that is only executed after mocking. One solution is to use a lambda or another function to delay the evaluation of `tk.StringVar`:

```
@dataclass
class Factory:
    _textvariable: tk.StringVar = field(
        default_factory=lambda: tk.StringVar(), init=False, repr=False
    )
```